# How to show the Heading of a Sub-Report on each page?

Tags: reporting, subreport, componentone, heading

What property do i need to set in the C1Report Designer to display the heading of my sub report on each new page.

```
Repeat = true
```

With that property set, the sub report does not show the heading on each new page. It does work fine for the `Main Report` tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a Grouping on the primary key field for the sub-report. Then check the header and footer section. Then set the repeat = true for the header and footer section.

Comment: my subreport doesnt have a primary key, now what should I do?