# Subreport headers are missing in the subsequent pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, crystal-reports

[image][image]I am working on generating reports for two table. Table1 contains fields Parcel id..(pk),purpose,owner,remarks etc specific to that item and table 2 contains item details like
item description,grossweight,net weight price,rupees,pieces etc.......

here parcel contains many items.... in a single report we have to show like

ParcelOwner : Test Owner
Remarks     : No Remarks
Address     : Address

below i have to show item details in that parcel in tabular format

Desc    Grossweoght   netweight   price

item1   100            200        1000

etc..... for each item here there may be ard 20 to 40 items.

i put main details in a report and item details in subreport. after detail sections of main report i inserted subreport. subreport spans over more than one page . here in third page i am not able to see subreport headers like Desc.....grossweight

i did grouping too by package id still i am not able to get that headers in subsequent pages. using vs2010 crystal reports and access database

Comment: Remember that you have to format your subreport just like a regular report. So if you want to see headers on every page, you have to format that in the subreport. It would help a lot if you could show screenshots of your report structures.

Comment: Is the subreport starting from page3 or it starts from page1?

Answer (score 1):

That is not easy task, Because header is always come from and for main report , not from sub-report.

You can set this header designing in sub-report's header section.

So it will come in each page page of sub-report section (but I think this will not work for you)

or

Other option is you create header portion in a group section in main report , where you put sub-report. and define condition for hide-show via shared variable will check that subreport have data or not. (like in this link where footer disable,you just header enable )
[How to suppress page footer for only sub report in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758522/how-to-suppress-page-footer-for-only-sub-report-in-crystal-reports)

please check this link too.

[How to show the Heading of a Sub-Report on each page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431497/how-to-show-the-heading-of-a-sub-report-on-each-page)

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3380866

Comment: ajay,i put header sections only in Sub-Report. when i tried to put header section in group header, records gets spanned into pages... each record displayed in separate pages with headers.here i did grouping by packageid which include itemes.

Comment: one more point. subreport starts from page2 after main details report. here in mainreport they want to show values as in form view and not in gridview ..  i added two details a and b for main report which shows details in form view and then i put subreport in details b after main details ends.

Comment: You just create a second section of group like group-footer-A,group-footer-B etc. and header and subreport put in separate footer section .And set properties "can grow" to true of section and . Also set suppress section properties true in section-expert by right click on any section.

Answer (score 0):

Ajay's second option will work.
From the main report right click your report and select format object. from the options select 
close borders on page break also. This will close the report borders.

Keep the object together option will take the entire subreport to the new page.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by adding a group section to the sub-report here in my case by packageid.... and items belong to a packageid ( one - many relationship).

Then remove the Group header section label ( added automatically to the group header section once u did grouping by package id).

Now add fields to group header section.

By right clicking group header section - select group expert -> repeat group header on each page.

then add sub-report (  delete sub-report link if present already i main report) and then right click sub-report and  uncheck "Keep Object Together" or else your sub-report will get displayed in new page instead of getting displayed immediately below the main report.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple trick for this you don't need to get messy with this grouping stuff at all. Select the sub report for with you want to display the header it will be highlighted in orange then right click for report properties and in the format tab of properties the last option is show sub report headers .change the value to Yes (Default is NO).

Comment: bullet your answer might be better.